# Using a pandas dataframe with timeseries data as basis for optimization with SciPy

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe (dfA). The Dataframes dfB, dfP and dfR should be calculated by the optimization. With ScipPy minimize I am trying to find the values for dfB and dfP where the sum of the Residuals in dfR is at a Minimum. (dfR=dfA-(dfB+dfP))

```
dataA ={'LP1':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]}   #values for dfA
dataB ={'b':[5,5,5,5,5,5,5]}      #dummy values for dfB
dataP ={'p':[3,3,3,3]}               #dummy values for dfP

dfA = pd.DataFrame(dataA, columns=['LP1'], index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
dfB = pd.DataFrame(dataB, columns=['b'], index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
dfP = pd.DataFrame(dataP, columns=['p'], index=[3,4,5,6])
```

I have set up the following constraints:

```
    #defining constraints
cons = (
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] + x[1] - int(dfA.max())},   # sum of b and p not greater than max amount of dfA
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0]},                           # x[0] 0 or higher
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[1]},                           # x[1] 0 or higher
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0]-100},                           # x[0] < 100
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[1]-100},                           # x[1] <100
        )
```

I have defined the optimization function as follows:

```
    def optGoal(b, p, dfA, dfB, dfP):

         dfB['b'] = b                             # set df Values to b, constant value for all existing indices
         dfP['p'] = p                              # set df Values to p, constant value for all existing indices

         dfR = dfA['LP1'] - (dfB['b'].add(dfP['p'], fill_value=0))         # df Residual = df Profile - (dfB + dfP) but fill the NAN values --- dfB['b'].add(dfP['p'], fill_value=0)
    return dfR.sum()
```

I call the minimization as follows:

```
  print spo.minimize(lambda x: optGoal(x[0], x[1], dfA, dfB, dfP), [0,0], method='COBYLA', constraints = cons, options={'maxiter':50000})      # optimization and printing result
```

But the optimization runs without success:

```
      status: 2
    nfev: 50000
   maxcv: 0.0
 success: False
     fun: -402779.92870763224
       x: array([ 43388.11278667,  24835.78480024])
 message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'
```

As a result I would like to have the value for dfB (index 1 to 7) and dfP (index 3 to 6) which lead to the Minimum sum of residulas (dfR).

As in the initial dfB and dfP creation, there should be one value in dfB covering index 1 to 7 and one value in dfP for index 3 to 6.

Can you help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: sorry I posted my comment as an answer by mistake.

Comment: no  problem. Thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: How do you convert floats < 0 to int >= 0?

Comment: And what are the values of dfR for hours not between 00:01 and 06:00?

Comment: Also "values in dfB and dfC should the same for all the hours within the year (constant across all hours in each dataframe)" is not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: The dfR should be calculated as dfR =dfA-(dfB+dfC). So for the hours outside 01:00 and 06:00 in dfR there would just be dfA-dfB.

Comment: The hours 01:00 to 06:00 would have for example a value of 20 in each hour of dfC.  And in dfB all hours would have a value of 30. So the value would be different between dfB and dfC but within the single dataframes it would the same.  The results of the optimization should be integer values for dfB and dfC by which the sum of dfR is minimized.

Comment: I cannot say I understand better. Please post code showing how the dataframes would be created and how the condition would be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective function is decreasing on both variables with a steeper slope on b so in order to minimize it you have to increase b as much as possible, then p if you still had some margin (you don't). This gives you b=dfA.max(), p=0 as the values that minimize the function. Using a computer for this is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. But I digress.

Your constraints do not match your intent (as stated in the comments). You want this:

```
cons = (
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  int(dfA.max()) - x[0] - x[1]},   # sum of b and p not greater than max amount of dfA
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0]},                           # x[0] 0 or higher
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[1]},                           # x[1] 0 or higher
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  100 - x[0]},                           # x[0] < 100
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  100 - x[1]},                           # x[1] < 100
        )
```

Using these constraints your call to `spo.minimize()` approximates the solution quite well:

```
  status: 1
    nfev: 99
     fun: -210.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
       x: array([  7.00000000e+01,  -1.73472348e-18])
   maxcv: 1.7347234759768071e-18
 success: True
```

It surprises me that the computed solution is not in the feasible region. I am not familiar with scipy optimization or numeric optimization in general so I do not know if this is to be expected. Well, I guess it is.

Comment: I have tried to Phrase the Problem with a better example and code.

Comment: @Markus see my edit. I think the constraints are wrong. The comments make sense but the functions do not match them and actually make your problem unbounded below again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting exactly the same result as above now.

Comment: I have changed the objective function to 'return abs(dfR.sum())' and I am getting the result: 'x: array([ 29.7386825 ,  17.95748859])' which seems a bit strange to me, as I am getting 'x: array([ 40 ,  0])' as a result with Excel solver. The Excel solver solution seems better as the sum of the residual is exactly 0.